# Axios ignores Set-Cookie when running in backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, axios, backend

I use axios on **server-side** to make requests like this:

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://10.10.10.10:3000',
    withCredentials: true,
});
const res = await instance.get('/api');
```

But I found out that it ignores all cookies. How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There might be possibilities that cookies are secure in nature. So u can't grab it. However, If you can validate with below-given code.

```
const axios = require('axios')
async function start() {
    const data = await axios.get("https://next.json-generator.com/api/tags")
    console.log(data.headers)
}
start()
```

Comment: I tried to do this, and there is a 'Set-Cookie'. It s just that axios ignores them. I also tried requests module in Python, and that works to save cookies

Comment: can you try directly , axios.request({baseURL: 'http://10.10.10.10:3000',
    withCredentials: true, url: '/api'})